# Angular router.navigate not working with cell click in tabulator.info js

Tags: angular, typescript, tabulator

Im using [tabulator.info](http://tabulator.info) js in my angular project to load table. This has [Angular Framework Support](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/frameworks#angular) as mentioned in their docs. I have a action column to place edit button in that column formatter. The problem is that `routerLink` is also not working and the `this.router.navigate` in cell click function is also not working. `this.router.navigate` throws the following error

> cannot read property navigate of undefined

but `alert()` function inside the cell click is triggered.

I'm new to Angular. Please assist. I'm using this tabulator as component and using it as mentioned in their docs.

Imports

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

OnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.columnNames = [
      {
        title: "Question",
        field: "description"
      },
      {
        title: "Total Answers",
        field: "",
        formatter: function (cell) {
          return cell.getRow().getData().answers.length;
        }
      },
      {
        title: "Feedback Type",
        field: "feedbackType"
      },
      {
        title: "Action",
        field: "",
        formatter: function (cell) {
          //cell - the cell component
          //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
          //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered

          return `<a [routerLink]="/feedbackquestion/${cell.getRow().getData().id}/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse text-white"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>`; //return the contents of the cell;
        },
        cellClick: function (e, cell) {
          //e - the click event object
          //cell - cell component
          this.router.navigate([`/feedbackquestion/${cell.getRow().getData().id}/edit`]);
        },
      }
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're providing your cell click listener as a normal function, therefore the context inside the function changes and `this` is undefined.

To keep the context of your component class, you need to provide your listener as a so-called [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
// ...

cellClick: (e, cell) => {
  this.router.navigate([`/feedbackquestion/${cell.getRow().getData().id}/edit`]);
},

// ...
```

Comment: You saved my day. Works fine thanks. But would it be much cleaner if the `routerLink` in `a` tag in the `cellformatter()` is made to work? This way I can have **multiple buttons** inside the same cell with different functionality for each button click?